# Everscale blockchain. difference between tvm.rawReserve and tvm.accept

Tags: solidity, everscale

I can't find in any way what is the difference between tvm.rawReserve(address(this).balance, 0) и tvm.accept()?

Answer (score -1):

Before executing a smart contract:

- the total amount of `ever` on the contract address and those who came with message is considered (for external message 0, for internal how many were sent)
- [storage fee](https://docs.everscale.network/arch/fee-calculation) is deducted from this amount
- [execution](https://docs.everscale.network/arch/executor#transaction-executor-message-processing-general-scheme) of the smart contract begins

For payment for the execution of a smart contract, it is always debited from the account balance.

if it is an external message (and 0 coins were transferred with it)
that is, a small credit for which you can check the require and, if something is wrong, cancel the transaction. in this case, nothing will be removed from the account balance.

If the checks were successful and it is necessary to execute the rest of the function code, payment for the execution of the transaction is made from the balance of the contract:

- [tvm.accept()](https://github.com/tonlabs/TON-Solidity-Compiler/blob/master/API.md#tvmaccept) — no gas limit
- [tvm.rawReserve(uint value, uint8 flag)](https://github.com/tonlabs/TON-Solidity-Compiler/blob/master/API.md#tvmrawreserve) — set the gas limit, that is, we reserve part of the funds and it will not be possible to spend more than this value. See also [tvm.setGasLimit(uint g)](https://github.com/tonlabs/TON-Solidity-Compiler/blob/master/API.md#tvmsetgaslimit).